# Sharepoint web service error 0x81020030 when adding new list item

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I am trying to add a new listitem using the sharepoint list service. But Iam getting this error in the result xml from sharepoint

"0x81020030Invalid file name.  The file name you specified could not be used.  It may be the name of an existing file or directory, or you may not have permission to access the file."

The strange thing is its working fine if i call from my local machine but fails in qa env.

This is the code that connects to service

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("use", "pwd", "domain");

SPCalendarService.ListsSoapClient client = new SVMEvents.SPCalendarService.ListsSoapClient("ListsSoap", "url");

```
            System.Xml.XmlNode ResultNode = client.UpdateListItems("EventList Name", inputXml);
```

Any ideas why this error comes... I am trying to add a new listitem.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means the list where you are trying to add the list item is corrupted.
Could you access to this list with the browser? Or add new items?

Comment: Yes I can open the list item and i am able to post to the list from my local, it does not work from the dev server

Comment: In that case I recommend you recreate the list and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a mistake by Microsoft in reporting the error: for some reason, this error is returned if one of the columns is corrupt. Try finding out whether any columns got corrupted and removing them and adding them again. Here's [a post that someone wrote about how he got a column corrupted and got that error](http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2013/01/sharepoint-error-0x81020030-invalid.html).

Answer (score 0):

This message also appears if you run out of disk space on DB server.